# public hotspot: Tor vs Antivirus Safe area?

Tags: tor, safe-browsing-filter, hotspot

I'm surfing through a public hotspot, I would like to login on my Facebook account with the minimum risk of being intercepted by any cracker connected to the same WiFi. I have both Tor browser and Bitdefender Safepay installed and working and I wonder which one is the best for my purposes.

while connected on a public WiFi, is it safer to use Tor browser or an antivirus Safe zone (Bitdefender Safepay in this case)?

Comment: You should use https://Facebookcorewwwi.onion/ to connect to Facebook via Tor.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: "Tor Browser *plus being careful and ready*" should be completely equivalent to "Safepay through BitDefender WiFi Premium protection".

In your scenario, both are *per se* equally secure. The data being sent on the air is encrypted, so connections to HTTPS sites **without** either Tor or BitDefender, *and* connections to plain HTTP sites **with** either of them, are all secure, even if protocol vulnerabilities must be considered (e.g. vulnerable HTTPS on some old web server).

But there is yet another possibility -- that the WiFi access point itself is malicious. In that case it can try and mount a MitM attack *and* try to take over your "view" of the Tor network, identifying itself as a safe node and running a virtual exit point. This requires significant computing power, but the AP could actually be an Intel Core i7 with a suitable WiFi network card for all you know. Both HTTPS and Tor connections would be vulnerable, even if you *should* see some sort of Certification Authority warning (unless, of course, the CA is backdoored - this would only be theoretically possible for government-level attackers, though).

In this second scenario, BitDefender would be more reliable (again, unless someone got to BitDefender) because their "WiFi protection" is actually a VPN to BitDefender's servers, and the Safepay browser directly interfaces with them with mutual authentication (this also for billing purposes - WiFi protection isn't free). An attacker might be easily able to impersonate a BitDefender customer to the server, but wouldn't be able to trick Safepay into believing that he possesses a valid BitDefender server certificate unless he *does*.